# Does there exist regular planar pentagon?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

How to prove or disprove that the boundary of any convex body in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (treated as a surface) includes 5 points which form a regular planar pentagon?

Comment: I asked that in [Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/187083/does-the-boundary-of-a-convex-body-contain-a-regular-planar-pentagon) and was answered.

Comment: And the answer appears to be that the answer to the question is unknown.

Comment: The simplest convex body in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a tetrahedron, right? Has the question been answered for a tetrahedron in the first place?

Comment: @Han de Bruijn: This is trivial: take a regular pentagon which lies on any face of a tetrahedron.

Comment: @user64494: Oops, wrong picture in mind :-(

Comment: It reminds my the [Inscribed square problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem): Consider a Jordan curve in the plane. Do they exist $4$ distinct points of the curve which are the vertices of a square?
This is still an open problem but it is know to be true if the curve is convex. If I remember correctly the proof of the convex case is not so hard. I wonder if we could generalize it to answer your question

Comment: More generally we could even consider the question "If $S$ is the boundary of a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$, do there exist always $n+2$ points on $S$ which form a regular planar polygon".

Comment: Suppose the body is a [pentagonal prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_prism)... Unless you meant 'the boundary of *every* convex body in $\Bbb R^3$'...?

Comment: @CiaPan: The meaning was perfectly clear until you came along...

Answer (score 2):

This is about a special case raised by Han de Bruijn: yes, you can inscribe a regular planar pentagon in a regular tetrahedron.

And you can do that in many ways, probably. Here is one of them.

Take a regular tetrahedron $ABCD$ with the edge length equal $1$. 
Let $E$ be a point on the $BC$ edge at distance $x$ from $B$. Similary $F$ on $DC$, $x$ apart from $D$.
The triangle $\triangle EFA$ is isosceles, degenerating continuously from the equilateral $\triangle BDA$ to the segment $CA$ as $x$ changes from $0$ to $1$.
That means $\epsilon = \angle EAF$ changes from $60^\circ$ to $0$. 'Somewhere' during the change it is $\epsilon = 36^\circ$. Where?

Let $y=AE=AF$ and $z=EF$. Due to the law of cosines in $\triangle ABE$ $$y^2 = 1^2 + x^2 - 2\cdot 1\cdot x\,\cos(\angle ABE) = x^2 + x + 1$$ and by the similarity $\triangle EFC \sim \triangle BDC$ $$EF = EC\times BD:BC$$ $$z = 1-x$$

In the isosceles $\triangle EFA$
$$\sin\frac\epsilon 2 = \frac z2:y$$
We want $\epsilon=36^\circ$:
$$\left .\sin 18^\circ = \frac{1-x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}} \ \ \right\vert \big(\big)^2$$
$$\sin^2 18^\circ = \frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2+x+1} = 1 - \frac{3x}{x^2+x+1}$$
$$\cos^2 18^\circ = \frac{3x}{x^2+x+1}$$
$$x^2+x+1 = \frac{3x}{\cos^2 18^\circ}$$
$$x^2+\left(1-\frac{3}{\cos^2 18^\circ}\right)x+1 = 0$$
The parenthesized expression is approx. $-2.317$ and one of the roots falls between $0$ and $1$:
$$x\approx 0.573$$
Once we have $36^\circ$ at $A$ we can fit a regular pentagon $JKLMN$ in the $\triangle EFA$ so that $JK \subset FA$, $LM \subset AE$, $KL \parallel EF$. If it is too small or too big, scale it so that $N$ becomes the midpoint of $EF$.

Comment: This is a special case (the regular case) of the special case (the tetrahedron) raised by Hans de Bruijn.